# New synonyms aren't being used

Tags: solr

I'm having some difficulty in getting new synonyms to work with SOLR.  What's odd is that the sample entries in the sysnonyms.txt file that comes with the distribution work.  Anything new that I add does not.

For instance, synonyms.txt had the following example:

> GB,gib,gigabyte,gigabytes

I am then querying a field call "subject" using one of the above terms.

> subject:gb
>
> subject:gib
>
> etc...

Regardless of which of those terms I use in my query, I get the same result set back as expected.

Next, I added the following line to synonyms.txt:

> ibm, i.b.m., international business machine

And I made sure that in schema.xml, the fieldtype text_general (the fieldtype used by the field "subject") has the SynonymFilterFactory enabled for index as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Finally, since my data is in a mysql database, I then re-imported all the data with a dataimport, assuming this is what I need to do to reindex.

However, while a query for subject:ibm" returns multiple results, a query for "subject:i.b.m." returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, I have a partial answer to my own question.  The query seems to be having trouble with the "periods" in "i.b.m.".  As a test, I added another related word "bbbbb" associated with ibm and that works.  Now I just need to figure out how to get acronyms with periods to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe I figured it out and it now seems to be working the way I intended.

I replaced StandardTokenizerFactory with ClassicTokenizerFactory and also added ClassicFilterFactory to the chain.  The net result is that I end up with tokens with the periods stripped out, and that seems to work.

So, here is my updated definition for text_general:

```
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Do you have any references or could you explain how you came about to this solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the synonyms filter know what tokenizer is used for tokenizing the input text:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <!--- ... -->
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!--- ... -->
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```